# Unexpected RegExp work in Python 2.7 on non ascii symbols

Tags: python, regex

I use regex to find words in sentences. But the problem described in code below emerged.
it works all fine on http://www.regexr.com/
but python does not match on non-ascii variant

```
import re
#ascii
pat = u"(tes?ts?)"
ttt = re.finditer(pat, u"test and tets")
print ttt.next().start()
print ttt.next().start()
# this works fine

#russian
pat = u"(молоде?цы?)"
ttt = re.finditer(pat, u"молодец и молодцы")
print ttt.next().start()
print ttt.next().start()
# this does not match anything - throws iterator error
```

Appreciate your help! Thank you
UPD: output + traceback

```
0
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in <module>
StopIteration
```

UPD2: changing the pattern to this

```
pat = u"(молод[е]?ц[ы]?)"
ttt = re.finditer(pat, u"молодец и молодцы")
print ttt.next().start()
print ttt.next().start()
```

resulted in matching the first word but no the second

```
18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this, could you add the output of `print repr(pat)` and `print repr(u"молодец и молодцы")`?

Comment: You mention it throws an iterator error. Please [edit] the traceback into your question.

Comment: If you want to test something for python use a tool for python: www.pythex.org

Comment: Casimir your site matches correctly, however I get my error with code above at http://repl.it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are saving the file with the right encoding? Python 2.7.5+ on Ubuntu works file for me when I declare the enconding on the top of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
#ascii
pat = u"(tes?ts?)"
ttt = re.finditer(pat, u"test and tets")
print(ttt.next().start())
print(ttt.next().start())
# 0, 9

#russian
pat = u"(молоде?цы?)"
ttt = re.finditer(pat, u"молодец и молодцы")
print(ttt.next().start())
print(ttt.next().start())
# 0, 10
```

Comment: BoppreH, adding your line with encoding or this one "# coding=utf-8" didn't help

Comment: I use python plugin for intelliJ IDEA, and AFAIK it uses utf-8 by default for code files, so it must not be the source of it